# Specify color for Cluster elements in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm new to R and I would like to get some info.
I've formed three intersecting clusters using **clusplot** in **R**.
All the three clusters are of different colors(I have made use of shade and color attribute to do this)
Now,I would like to change color of each element in the cluster. I found that all the elements in the three clusters have the same color which is green
Is there a way that I could specify the color of all the elements for each cluster. Below is the screenshot and code[image]

```
 kmres <- kmeans(data1,centers=3,iter.max=100,nstart=25)
 clusplot(data1,kmres$cluster,color=TRUE,shade=TRUE)
```

Here is my sample data set
I have three columns M,G, PTS. 
**M**   **G**   **PTS**
82  209 521

Is there a way to do this(particularly using clusplot)?

Comment: please share an example dataset with us using `dput()`.

Comment: I've added the sample data set to the question now.Pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the help page you can find the col.p attribute that may help you.

```
data1<-iris[,-5]
kmres <- kmeans(data1,centers=3,iter.max=100,nstart=25)
clusplot(data1,kmres$cluster,color=TRUE,shade=TRUE,col.p = kmres$cluster)
```

### [image: Example]

The only problem from my point of view is that the ellipses are colored by their density, and the result may be a bit confusing, but the points colors are different.